# Подключение к базе через Apache spark на java

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-spark

Как подключиться к базе данных через spark sql?

Как я понял из того что есть в интернете это должно выглядить примерно так:

```
Dataset<Row> response = dataFrameReader.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","actor",new Properties());
```

Но при этом выходит ошибка

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

Вот мои dependency

```
    group 'jameslee'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 11

idea {
    project {
        jdkName = '11'
        languageLevel = '14'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.10', version: '2.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.10', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.13'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'

}


jar {
    zip64 true
    archiveName = "StackOverFlowSurvey-spark.jar"
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.sparkTutorial.sparkSql.StackOverFlowSurvey'
    }

    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

Comment: добавьте ошибку в вопрос

Comment: Покажите ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я у меня оказывается была ошибка из за версии mysql-connecter, так получается что при подключении MySql 5-ой версии и ниже выходит ошибка с подключением. Надо было просто поменять на 8-ую версию

Comment: Абсолютно верно. Что и указывала ошибка!